# How to read the file using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file that has to be read and the output should be appended to the output.txt file how can i do this?

Comment: Wow and you couldn't find answer to this on existing SO answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for this??

```
cat fileneed2bread >> output.txt
```